# How to add URL sufix to custom route?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I created an extension with the custom route: http://example.com/myroute/.

How can I do it like this: http://example.com/myroute**.html** ?

How can I add '.html' at the end of my route?

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is to create a custom URL rewrite.

From Magento BO, go to **Marketing** => **SEO & Search** => **URL Rewrites** => **Add URL Rewrite**.

1. Request Path: myroute.html
2. Target Path: myroute
3. Redirect Type: No